# Unable to Fetch Data From Db.sdf ( Compact Edition)File If I run win form application on other system

Tags: winforms, sql-server-ce

I have developed a Winforms application. I have used SQL Server Compact database (`.sdf`). It's a local db. I'm able to run on my system. But If I run on another system, I am getting error. I used `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand`, `SqlCeDataReader` classes. And I used VS Report Viewer to view the report from the database.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting?!?!? We can't see your friend's screen, and we cannot read your mind, either - you'll have to **tell us!**

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. The problem is solved. I have set full file access permission to ".sdf" file. Now its accessible.